# extract filename from path

Tags: php, regex

i need to get filename from file path string. For example, from this string `\abc\def\filename.txt` i need to get `filename.txt`

trying to do this with regexp:

```
$filepath="abc\filename.txt";
$filename = preg_replace("/.+\\/","",$filepath);
```

but it gives me an error. What regex i should use to solve this?

Comment: There's no reason to replace characters with nothing using preg_replace. It's more direct to just use preg_match instead. (See my answer for how).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you should use the function basename instead:

```
$filepath = 'abc\filename.txt';
$filename = basename($filepath);
```

edit: important note, you need to use single quotes when you have backslashes in your strings, else escape them properly.

note: this *will not* work:

```
$filepath = "abc\filename.txt";
$filename = basename($filepath);
```

because you're variable $filepath infact holds:

`abc[special char here equalling \f]ilename.txt`

another edit:
this regex works too..

```
$filepath = '\def\abc\filename.txt';
$basename = preg_replace('/^.+\\\\/', '', $filepath);
```

all that was wrong with your original was that you had double-quotes rather than single, and backslash needs double escaped (\\ rather than \).

Comment: @nathan: That won't work, it will give you `abcilename.txt`

Comment: @casablanca: Let's hope if others also try that code :) Doesn't seem to work for me though.

Comment: @nathan: I believe problem was in `\\`, the basename worked fine with `/` in the path.

Comment: @sAc good fix on your q, also the fix for basename is in the edit now - confused us for a minute there!

Comment: @nathan: yes because op was using back slash +1 anyways ;)

Comment: FYI: `\f` should be formfeed.

Comment: @Billy: I thought so too, but surprisingly, PHP doesn't seem to interpret `\f`.

Answer (score 5):

**Two solutions:**

1. [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
2. [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) with [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

---

**1: [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)**

Ok, so the problem is that you are using backslashes. You have to make sure that you **do not use double quotes** for defining your filepath, since the backslash is interpreted as an escape sequence. Use single quotes.

Additionally, with a regex, it's much simple to get a filename by moving from the back of the path until you hit a backslash.... the trick is that a backslash is `\\\\`.. [here's why](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html)

Finally, you don't want to use preg_replace. Just find the filename with preg_match:

```
<?php
  // Use single quotes or the backslash will be interpreted as an esacpe sequence
$filepath = '\abc\def\filename.txt';

  // You have to use 4 backslashes to represent your single backslash 
  // The regex picks the characters that are NOT \ from the end of the path
$pattern = '/[^\\\\]+$/';

  // Use $matches to store the match
preg_match($pattern, $filepath, $matches);

  // Display answer now, or use later
echo $matches[0];
?>
```

---

**2: [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) with [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)**

As others said, `basename()` is a good option. Another option, if there's any chance that you may also need the directory or other path information later down the line is to use [`pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

The problem is that both basename and pathinfo assume forward slashes, so you must convert your backslashes to forward slashes:

Example:

```
<?php
  // Make sure to use single quotes
$filepath='abc\filename.txt';
  // Replace backslash with forward slash
$filepath = str_replace('\\', '/', $filepath);
$path_parts = pathinfo($filepath);

  // This is the answer you want
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";

  // But you also have access to these
echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

Comment: That won't work either, also he needs regex solution as indicated by him.

Comment: @sAc I thought OP indicated that regex wasn't working very well... gtg but will try in a few

Comment: It works only when you use a slash (/) rather than backslash in the path. +1 now :)

Comment: @sAc Thanks for the heads up. I rewrote the code using a pretty simple regex that just gets all characters from the back of the path that aren't a backslash. Also, fixed the original code with slash replace.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
$filepath='abc\filename.txt';
$basename = preg_replace('/^.+[\\\\\\/]/', '', $filepath);
echo $basename;
```

**Result:**

```
filename.txt
```

Comment: that won't work for the filepath `\abc\def\filename.txt` it'll return '`def\filename.txt`

Comment: @nathan: I believe problem was in `\\`, it works fine with /` in the path.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace("/[^\/]+.([^\.]+\.[a-z]{3,5})/i","$1","abc/filename.txt"); //return filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Why throw regex at such a simple problem?

```
$source = "/i/am/a/path.txt";
$pos = strrpos($source, '/');
$result = substr($source, $pos === FALSE ? 0 : $pos);
```

EDIT: I have not tried this -- I don't have a working PHP server handy. There **might** be an off-by-one error with substr and strrpos, but if that's the case you just add or subtract one from `$pos`.

EDIT2: Here's a backslash version:

```
$source = "\\i\\am\\a\\path.txt";
$pos = strrpos($source, '\\');
$result = substr($source, $pos === FALSE ? 0 : $pos);
```

Comment: OP has backslashes, so you can't double quote $source and you have to escape the backslash in $pos

Comment: @Peter: Added a backslash version.