# display file name in while loop without url

Tags: php

[image]
   I want to display only the file name without displaying the url.
I want to replace the file name instead of 'document '.

```
 while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
            { 
             $i=$i+1;
             $next=$fet['f_name'];
             echo '<h4><a class="astext" href="'.$next.'" title="'.$next.'" target="_blank" download>Document'.$i.'</a></h4>';
            }
```

if I replace the word 'document' to $next it shows full url as http://www.sample/txt/1/sample.doc I need to display sample.doc.

```
echo '<h4><a class="astext" href="'.$next.'" title="'.$next.'" target="_blank" download>"'.$next.'"</a></h4>';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278120/extract-filename-from-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included  $next1 = basename($next);

```
while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
        { 
         $i=$i+1;
         $next=$fet['f_name'];
         $next1 = basename($next);
         echo '<h4><a class="astext" href="'.$next.'" title="'.$next.'" target="_blank" download>'.$next1.'</a></h4>';
        }
```

Its working now.

Comment: Just for an information :) There is an option `answer your own question` in the edit option.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options.

Assume you have `$next=http://www.sample/txt/1/sample.doc`

**Option 1:**

This works if you think `http://www.sample/txt/1/` is same to all folders.

ltrim($next,"http://www.sample/txt/1/");

**Option 2:**

use `basename($next)`

This will extract the sample.doc

Comment: option 2 is suitable for my problem.I created the folder dynamically for some reason. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $link = "http://www.sample/txt/1/sample.doc";
    $linkArray = explode('/', $link);

    echo $linkArray[count($linkArray)-1];

?>
```

**Magesh Kumaar** also provide good one

```
<?php

$link = "http://www.sample/txt/1/sample.doc";
echo basename($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url  = "http://www.sample/txt/1/sample.doc";
echo strstr($url,"sample.");
```

?>

> [For More Details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)